# how to find plus or minus x percent of a number

Tags: java, math

I have two quantities in my class:

```
aToday, aYesterday
```

I have a number X between 1 and 100 entered by user.

Say he enters 10.

What I want to do is to find out if aToday is 10 percent more then aYesterday or 10 percent less then aYesterday.

How to write this ?

I am not getting 10 percent less. X percent more will be:

```
if(aToday > (x/100 * aYesterday))
```

How to check for 10 percent more ?

Comment: if(aToday < (100.0-x)/100.0 * aYesterday

Answer (score 3, accepted):

10% more:

```
if ( aToday > aYesterday*1.1 )
```

10% less

```
if ( aToday < aYesterday*0.9 )
```

Of course make sure you are calculating with for example `double` instances and not `int` instances, or you will have unexpected results due to the rounding

**Edit**

For a percentage x

x more (for example x = 10 -> 10 percent more)

```
if ( aToday > ( 1 + (x/100) ) * aYesterday )
```

and x less

```
if ( aToday < ( 1 - (x/100) ) * aYesterday )
```

The remark about using the correct types remains of course valid

Comment: The questions states 'How to check for 10 percent more ?', but I will adjust my answer for a random percentage

Answer (score 0):

```
hasIncreasedMoreThanXPct = (aToday > 1 + (X / 100) * aYesterday  ) 
hasDecreasedMoreThanXPct = (aToday < 1 - (X / 100) * aYesterday  )
```

Comment: `? true : false` is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

Basically the range allowed for say **X** percent is between

`( (100 - x)  * aYesterday / 100 , (100 + x ) * aYesterfday / 100 )`

Compute them and call them `(LowerBound , UpperBound)`

so your check becomes

```
    LowerBound  = (100 - x)  * aYesterday / 100;
    UpperBound  = (100 + x ) * aYesterfday / 100;
    if ( aToday > LowerBound || aToday < UpperBound ) 
    {
    }
```

If you want to take avoid division and truncation if everything is integer, you can multiple everything by 100.

```
    LowerBound  = (100 - x)  * aYesterday;
    UpperBound  = (100 + x ) * aYesterfday;
    HundredTimesaToday = 100 * aToday;
    if ( HundredTimesaToday > LowerBound || HundredTimesaToday < UpperBound ) 
    {
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static boolean isMoreThanPercentage(double a, double b, double percentage)
{
    return ((a / b) * 100 - 100) >= percentage; // Is a greater than b by percentage% of b or more?
}
```

For example:

`isMoreThanPercentage(20, 10, 50)` returns `true`, because 20 is greater than 10 by 100%.

Answer (score 0):

```
isMore = today > (1+x/100)*yesterday
isLess = today < (1-x/100)*yesterday
```